# Parallel.ForEach returning before object's method which makes rate limited API calls

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, parallel.foreach

I am working on a plugin for a program that needs to make API calls, I was previously making them all synchronously which, well it worked, was slow.

To combat this I am trying to make the calls asynchronous, I can make 10 per second so I was trying the following:

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    items.Values,
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 },
    async item => {
        await item.UpdateMarketData(client, HQOnly.Checked, retainers);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
);
```

`client` is an `HttpClient` object and the rest is used to build the API call or for the stuff done to the result of the API call. Each time `item.UpdateMarketData()` is called 1 and only 1 API call is made.

This code seems to be finishing very quickly and as I understand it, the program should wait for a `Parallel.ForEach()` to complete before continuing.

The data that should be set by `item.UpdateMarketData()` is not being set either. In order to make sure, I have even set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1` and the Delay to 3 seconds and it still finished very quickly despite having ~44 items to go though. Any help would be appreciated.

`UpdateMarketData()` is included below just in case it is relevant:

```
public async Task UpdateMarketData(TextBox DebugTextBox,HttpClient client,
    bool HQOnly, List<string> retainers)
{
    HttpResponseMessage sellers_result = null;
    try
    {
        sellers_result = await client.GetAsync(String.Format(
            "www.apiImCalling/items/{0}?key=secretapikey", ID));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(
            String.Format("{0} Exception caught.", e));
        sellers_result = null;
    }
    var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectMB>(
        sellers_result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    int count = 0;
    OnMB = false;
    LowestOnMB = false;
    LowestPrice = int.MaxValue;
    try
    {
        foreach (var x in results.Prices)
        {
            if (x.IsHQ | !(HQOnly && RequireHQ))
            {
                count++;
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    LowestPrice = x.PricePerUnit;
                }
                if (retainers.Contains(x.RetainerName))
                {
                    Retainer = x.RetainerName;
                    OnMB = true;
                    Price = x.PricePerUnit;
                    if (count == 1)
                    {
                        LowestOnMB = true;
                    }
                }
                if (LowestPrice == x.PricePerUnit
                    && x.RetainerName != Retainer)
                {
                    LowestOnMB = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(
            String.Format("{0} Exception caught.", e));
    }
}
```

Comment: is that worked for you , or helpful to you ?

Comment: I havn't had a chance to try it yet, its after 230 am here, and I am not really able of focusing on it, I will absolutely try to get this working tomorrow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`async` doesn't work with `Parallel`. One is asynchronous, the other is parallel, and these are two completely different styles of concurrency.

To restrict the concurrency of asynchronous operations, use `SemaphoreSlim`. E.g.:

```
var mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(10);
var tasks = items.Values.Select(item => DoUpdateMarketData(item)).ToList();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

async Task DoUpdateMarketData(Item item)
{
  await mutex.WaitAsync();
  try
  {
    await item.UpdateMarketData(client, HQOnly.Checked, retainers);
    await Task.Delay(1000);
  }
  finally { mutex.Release(); }
}
```

You may find [my book](https://stephencleary.com/book/) helpful; this is covered in recipe 11.5.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then parallel.for loop , you can make use of Task and wait for all task to complete.

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var val in items.Values)
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(val.UpdateMarketData(client, HQOnly.Checked, retainers)));

 try
 {
    // Wait for all the tasks to finish.
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    //make use of WhenAll method if you dont want to block thread, and want to use async/await 

    Console.WriteLine("update completed");
  }
  catch (AggregateException e)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("\nThe following exceptions have been thrown by WaitAll(): (THIS WAS EXPECTED)");
    for (int j = 0; j < e.InnerExceptions.Count; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n-------------------------------------------------\n{0}", e.InnerExceptions[j].ToString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: How does this limit the number of calls per second? It seems the OP has a limitation of 10 calls per second.

Comment: @PeterBons - he has to add logic related to that

Comment: I think you're trying to iterate through a collection that is not always containing a correct value (correct in a business context). Your foreach (var x in results.Prices) will not wait until you get a sellers_result  from GetAsync(). Try to log the content of your sellers_result   just to make sure you always get it right.